# Change image src with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code:

```
function EnableiPad(event) {
    var id = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-id");
    var status = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-status");    
    $.post("/Ipad/ChangeStatus", { id: id, enable: status }, onAjaxSuccess);
};
function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    var status = $(".button-enable").attr("data-status");

    if (status == 'true') 
    {
        $('#statusImg').attr("src", '/Content/img/disable.png');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#statusImg').attr("src", '/Content/img/enable.png');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change image  - `$('#statusImg').attr("src", '/Content/img/disable.png');`

**Update**

Here is my images:

```
@if (iPad.Enabled)
{
    <button  class="button-enable" data-original-title="Show timetable"  data-id="@iPad.Id" data-status="false" class="btn btn-mini" style="border: 0; background: transparent; box-shadow: none; padding: 0;">
        <img id="status" width="24" height="24" alt="Delete doctor" src="/Content/img/enable.png" />
    </button>
}
else
{ 
    <button id="statusDisable" class="button-enable" data-original-title="Show timetable"  data-id="@iPad.Id" data-status="true" class="btn btn-mini" style="border: 0; background: transparent; box-shadow: none; padding: 0;">
        <img id="status" width="24" height="24" alt="Delete doctor" src="/Content/img/disable.png" />
    </button>
}
```

Comment: you missed the last bracket. Is the actual code like that or this is just a typo?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. At which point does it fail - is `EnableiPad()` ever called? Is the Ajax request ever fired? Does the success callback ever come back? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: It seems valid. Probably the problem is in something subtle.

Comment: Any errors? Why are you handling the image change in the callback function when you don't seem to use the `data` from the callback? why not just do it prior to the `post` event?

Comment: `$('#statusImg').attr("src", '/Content/img/disable.png');` should work fine if selector is ok. Try to debug app more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**id** of your img tag is status, so it should be:

```
$('#status').attr("src", '/Content/img/disable.png');
```

Comment: On the page I have more than one image with this id? so I try to change id into class and than change the selector, but it works strange, it change not that image I have click before

Comment: id's must be unique, since you are using same id's for all thatswhy its not working, changing to class should work